# Stop pull to refresh in Microsoft Teams iOS app

Tags: microsoft-teams

While working on Microsoft Teams application, we tried stopping the `pull to refresh` functionality in `Microsoft Teams` iOS app. we have tried a couple of `css and JS fixes` but none of them worked.

Is there any SDK method or work-around to stop `pull to refresh`.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there no such API available to `stop pull to refresh`. Here is the list of available methods [microsoftTeams module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-latest)

Comment: Okay, is there any way that we can stop `pull to refresh` in MS Teams personal tab?

Comment: Its a platform feature and we cannot do that.

Comment: Yes, we are facing a number of issues after `pull to refresh`. @HunaidHanfee-MSFT is there any way that I can debug my application loaded as tabs in Microsoft Teams iOS app? Could you please guide me on that? thanks

Comment: If the app is running locally you can put debuggers and check. If you want to see DevTools, right now it is not supported see this [DevTools for Microsoft Teams Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools) Please see the note in the doc.